# wrong canonical in homepage with cs_seo

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I try cs_seo 3.1.0 in an installation of TYPO3 8.7.31. cs_seo prints canonical tags on every page. On most pages they are correct but not on the homepage. There i get this canonical:

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://mydomain.tld/?L=0" />
```

The L=0 Parameter is wrong - there is no other language in the site.

Any ideas how to get rid off this parameter? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason and a solution. It is a weird problem with realurl. In my installation exists more than one realurl-path-entries for every page. Sometimes they do have language parameters L=... instead of /en/ - i dont know why this sometimes occur. When one of this entries is on first place in the list of path entries then it appears in the canonical tag an in the preview in the seo panel.

Solution is to delete these wrong entries in the real url panel.